# Enyo js - populating menu

Tags: javascript, enyo

I am trying to dynamically populate a menu in Enyo js. But I couldn't find a proper way to do it. Though I tried combining it with jQuery, I wonder if there is an "Enyo" way of doing it.

```
{kind: "onyx.MenuDecorator", name: "keymapHolder", components: [
    {content: "Default"},
    {kind: "onyx.Menu", name: "keymapMenu", components:[

    ]
    }],
}
```

So I have to fill the components of the "keymapMenu" using a function rather than straightaway putting it inside the widget definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create menu items dynamically by calling `createComponents()`.  I've put together a fiddle for you that dynamically adds components to a menu. Note that if you want to clear out old items you'll need to call `destroy()` on each item that *isn't* the scroller for the menu.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RoySutton/hmyJt/5/